# Postman display base64 image as test result

Tags: base64, postman

I am trying to visualize a base64 img I receive in my response using the Postman Test feature.

My **JSON:**

```json
{
  ...,
  "result": {
    ...,
    "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/..."
  }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```js
let template = `
<img src='{{img}}'/>
`

pm.visualizer.set(template, { 
    img: pm.response.json().result.image
})
```

How can I display the base64 `image` inside the  tag / retrieve it from the Postman `pm` object?

Comment: Does this help? https://community.postman.com/t/visualize-api-response-base64-image-display/8058/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variant almost right, but you need to retrieve img data for the template in a proper way like following:

```
let template = `
<img src='{{img}}'/>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, { 
    img: pm.response.json()["result"]["image"]
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try console.log() on your `template` to see if it is resolving how you expect. I got your solution to work using a hard-coded base64 image of a little red dot

```js
const base64ImgData = `data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

const template = `
<img src="{{img}}">
`

pm.visualizer.set(template, {img: base64ImgData})
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSro9.png)

Comment: this prefix header `data:image/png;base64,` seems to be important for rendering :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but my API was just returning the JPG data. This worked for me:

```
let template = `
<img src='{{img}}'/>
`;

const imageSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + pm.response.json()["message"];
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
        img: imageSrc
});
```